# Efficient way to return select columns from Rails 4 ActiveRecord nested query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses
  end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end
```

I'm using the `:includes` function to return query result into one variable:

```
Address.includes(:person, :city).where("person_id = 1")
```

**It works as expected, except that I do not want the query to return every single column.**

Here's what I've tried:

- use `select` and specify table name and column names explicitly, e.g. "`city.name`", but Rails generates a big query with outer joins, that can be very costly, especially when there are lots of concurrent requests, so prefer a better solution.
- don't want to hard code complete and raw SQL statements, because of maintenance issue later on
- create a new "dummy" `belongs_to` relationship like in Address: `belongs_to :city_select_columns, -> { select('name') }, :class => 'City'`, but that doesn't work (actually I'm not sure if that `select` is even supported, only came across documentation about `where` so far).
- maybe define `scope` in City and Person? but I'm not sure how it should be defined or if it'd make sense to do it this way

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You said "It works as expected, except that I do not want the query to return every single column.", but which columns do you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses
    has_many :cities, :through => :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end
```

Then:

```
Person.find(1).cities.pluck(:name)
```

Looks like this generates an `INNER JOIN` but with indexes it shouldn't be too costly?

Comment: Could not get pluck to return more than one columns properly. I ended up using a raw join SQL. Tried to leverage the API, but guess sometimes brute force is just more efficient :/

Comment: I just tried `...pluck(:x,:y)` and it returned and array of arrays: `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]`... Is this not sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `select`?

```
Address.select(<output_columns>).includes(:person, :city).where("person_id = 1")
```

Comment: that's what I meant by using joins, just updated my question. with `.select('city.name, etc.')`, Rails generates a big query involving outer joins in the back end, I prefer not using that :/

Comment: in my case, 3 queries are generated with `:includes`, no joins

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a good query method using Rails' API, I ended up writing a raw inner join SQL, then call `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` to run it.